# Git/GitHub - Error when pushing files to a repository

Tags: git, github

I was attempting to add a lot of the company's files to a repository the other day with the "git push origin master" command when I was suddenly shown warnings that several files were larger than the recommended GitHub size and one error in particular that noted at least one file was too big to be pushed.  I tried removing them and it seemed like it worked at first.  However, once I committed that change and tried to push the files again, I got the exact same warnings and errors as before and I saw that the file count had increased by 4.  How can I exclude the files I removed?  There were only seven so I went through and removed them individually after backing them up on my hard drive but I have no clue of what to do.

Comment: are you talking about a .gitignore file?

Comment: put the filename into .gitignore and GIT will skip it when you try to push

Comment: I didn't think I'd need to do that because I removed the files with git rm (filename here).  I saw that they hadn't been removed from the root or something so I deleted them there and the file count increased again.

Comment: Github has a help page on this subject: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/

Comment: I just tried it and nothing improved.  I'm probably going to have to try deleting the repository we created (not the whole account) so I can start over and hopefully avoid this mess.

Comment: I've tried deleting the online repository and the local one so I can start over, and gave the same name to the new repository.  I removed all of the problem files and backed them up on my hard drive away from the repository.  AGAIN, I get the exact same issues and nothing seems to be working.  I'm at a complete loss at what to do.

Comment: I hate to post in rapid succession like this but I've "fixed" the issue.  The error doesn't seem to matter and all the files are there.